# Can JENKINS create build by excluding particular files?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am actually trying to ignore a particular file to be included in the build. Actually it is a thumb.db file which is automatically created whenever images are encountered in a folder. My solution contains the image folder. So basically, whenever the build is triggered from JENKINS, it will create the thumb.db file.

Is there any way, I can ignore the **Thumb.db** file from getting created via JENKINS?

I can switch off the **thumb.db** file from creation by switching it off from my windows, but I have to do it every time a build is created from JENKINS. So I want to ignore the thumb.db file from creation.

Below is the Job creation flow in my JENKINS from my current project:

**SCM**

I have used the Team Foundation Server Plugin and have mentioned my **SERVER URL** and **PROJECT PATH**

**POST BUILD** steps simply create the build to the staging location(folder Location)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635865/tfs-2012-gitignore-hgignore-equivalent). It might help you

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, on windows you can turn it off or on for the whole system and not for particular folders.
So you have to choose. On or off.

If you still want to keep it on, you'l have to handle this in your Jenkins build scripts. Remove any `thumbs.db` files after build is done.

If your output is an archive, make sure to exclude `thumbs.db` from it. All archives support an **exclude** flag.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So once a build is created via JENKINS, I have to manually remove the thumb.db file from the staging location?

Comment: Not manually. Have your build script do it. That's the whole magic in Jenkins. Code and automate all your work! If you add more details on what you are doing, I can give you technical ideas.

Comment: Thank you @Eldad. I have modified my question and added the information for pre and post build steps. Do I need to add any JENKINS plugin to get this job done?

Comment: Good, but what is the actual build? Do you have code to compile? Tests to run? System to start? How do the `thumb.db` files bother your build?

Comment: Actually, I am compiling my code through Visual Studio **MSBUILD** and my code contains and image folder that on encountering create the thumb.db file